# Does Amadeus API provide the total number of flights (arrivals and departures) for every 5 minutes in a specific airport?

Tags: api, amadeus

I am interested in storing the number of flights (arrivals and departures) for every 5 minutes in a specific airport.
Does Amadeus provide that functionality? Else is there another API which provides the count (not necessarily the results set) for this request?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, there is not a dedicated API for the functionality you are looking for. Maybe you could check out OAG https://www.oag.com/

Comment: @Anna Tsolakou I was looking for the same thing, the link helped. Thanks.